# Not able to write to all rows in .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write to `file2.csv` file by values from `file1.csv` file using a keyfile.csv which contains the mapping between two files as the two files don't have the same column order.

```
def convert():

    Keyfile = open('keyfile.csv', 'rb')
    file1 = open('file1.csv', 'rb')
    file2 = open('file2.csv', 'w')

    reader_Keyfile = csv.reader(Keyfile, delimiter=",")
    reader_file1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=",")
    writer_file2 = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=",")
    for row_file1 in reader_file1:
        for row_Keyfile in reader_Keyfile:
            for index_val in row_Keyfile:
                file2.write(row_file1[int(index_val)-1]+',')
    # Closing all the files     
    file2.close()
    Keyfile.close()
    file1.close()

# keyfile structure: 3,77,65,78,1,10,8...
# so 1st column of file2 is 3rd column of file1 ; 
# col2 of file 2 is col77 of file1 and so on
```

I'm only able to write only one row in `file2.csv`. It should have as many rows as there are in `file1.csv`. How do I move to the next row after one row is finished ? I'm assuming Loop should take care of that but that's not happening.What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are reading files whilst you are reading a file... Why? Why are you reading reader_Keyfile within reader_file1. You have a nested mess my friend refactor it before it kills us all! Try not to call things a1, file1 ect, very hard to understand.

Comment: Keyfile contains the mapping of column numbers e.g column 1 of file1 is column 5 of file2 that's why reading it. File1 file2 I just wrote as dummynames to avoid confusion but they have worked otherwise.

Comment: Screenshot of KeyFile contents would be helpful...

Comment: I'm sorry this is just to much of a twister, really you should just throw out the whole thing, break it up into seperate parts if you really need to have one file referencing another but I don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested looping is problematic as others mentioned. Instead, create the mapping outside of the row iteration, then write the rows based on the mapping. I use a `dict` object for this.

```
import csv

Keyfile = open('keyfile.csv', 'rb')
file_out = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",")
file_in = csv.writer(open('file2.csv', 'w'), delimiter=",")

mapDict = {}

# the first line in KeyFile convert to dict
reader = csv.reader(Keyfile, delimiter=',')
for i, v in enumerate(reader.next()):
    if v != ' ':
        mapDict[i] = int(v)


# re-index the row in file_in based on mapDict
for row in file_out:
    file_in.writerow([row[c] for c in mapDict.values()])
```

Comment: small point `keyfile` can have blank values `1, , ,77, 88, ,9` that means for that column there is no mapping hence should be left empty. Does your solution still hold in that case ?

Comment: made a small change to account for `' '` value in the key file. If you need to adjust for null string just change to `if v != ''`

Comment: this worked but the output I am getting is wrong somewhere. I will check it no problem thanks.

Comment: the `mapDict` assumes your KeyFile is zero-indexed (i.e., the first column is column `0`). Also, it's possible that I have the mapping backwards from what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

1. You should only read keyfile once and build a dict out of the mapping
2. You need to write a `\n` at the end of each line of your output file

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming the KeyFile is just one row, giving the mappings for all rows. Something like the following should work:

```
def convert():
    with open('keyfile.csv') as Keyfile, open('file1.csv', 'r') as file1, open('file2.csv', 'wb') as file2:
        mappings = next(csv.reader(Keyfile, delimiter=","))
        mappings = [int(x)-1 if x else None for x in mappings]

        reader_file1 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=",")
        writer_file2 = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=",")

        for row_file1 in reader_file1:
            row = [''] * len(mappings)
            for from_index, to_index in enumerate(mappings):
                if to_index != None:
                    row[to_index] = row_file1[from_index]
            writer_file2.writerow(row)
```

It assumes column mappings start from 1.

Comment: it seems like this should work but there is a small issue. in `keyfile` so it's structure is like `1, , ,77,88,2, , 3` there are some blank values that means for those index there is no matching column and should be written as empty .. according to your code i'm getting the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: I have made a small change, you can try again.

Comment: some error : `row[to_index] = row_file1[from_index]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType`

Comment: Are you sure your code matches this? It shouldn't be possible to have `None` with the `if` statement above.

Comment: some new error coming now : `row[to_index] = row_file1[from_index]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range ` . anyway i think it's okay i can take it from here, thanks for the help